# Android crash when starting activity?

Tags: java, android, crash

I have a new Intent Activity I want to open when a double click is registered, I know the double click is working properly, but every time I try to start the new activity it stops working ? (Force Quits)

code :

```
 imView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long thisTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                  if (thisTime - lastTouchTime < 250) {
                     // Double click
                      //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Double Tap Worked!", 10);
                      //toast.show();
                      lastTouchTime = -1;
                      Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), zoom.class);
                      startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                  } else {
                      // too slow
                      lastTouchTime = thisTime;
                  }
            }
         });
```

Comment: Paste what you get from the LogCat every time you have error

Comment: Post the Log, and make sure you have added your Activity to the AndroidManifest.xml (that's what I always forget and once my app crashes I remember to add it lol)

Answer (score 13):

You may not have put the second activity in the manifiest file

```
 <activity android:name="zoom"
           android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless you haven't shared the LogCat, I guess this is what you are looking for.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(YourClass.this, zoom.class);
```

Everytime you create new intent you send the caller of the new intent context, not the context of the view you are starting the Intent and add the activity to your manifest.