# Android: NullPointer after trying to make an intent after onTab on ItemizedOverly

Tags: android, google-maps, itemizedoverlay

I have a MapsActivity in a TabHostActivity where I put a custom ItemizedOverlay over the map to display custom OverlayItems.

In my ItemizedOverlay class the onTab method looks as follows

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    listener.onPoiTap(this.poiList.get(index));
    return true;
}
```

where the listener variable is a custom onTabListener which is implemented in the maps Activity as follows:

```
@Override
public void onPoiTap(PointOfInterest poi) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(getParent(), PointOfInterestActivity.class);

    ActivityStack activityStack = (ActivityStack) this.getParent();
    activityStack.push(new Date().getTime() + "", intent);
    // Toast.makeText(this, "Title: " + poi.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The Toast after the comment works and shows the right title, but the call of the intent makes the app crash and shows a log without any references to my code:

```
I/InputReader( 2284): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.749 ]
I/InputDispatcher( 2284): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputDispatcher( 2284): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputDispatcher( 2284): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputReader( 2284): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=]
I/InputDispatcher( 2284): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher( 2284): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher( 2284): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
E/InputEventReceiver(22509): Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:548)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:683)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7337)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2410)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2145)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2109)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1462)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2472)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2057)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2109)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1462)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2472)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2057)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2109)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1462)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2472)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2057)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7520)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3374)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3306)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4400)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4378)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4482)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(22509):  a
D/AndroidRuntime(22509): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(22509): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410662a0)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(22509): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:683)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7337)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2410)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2145)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2109)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1462)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2472)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2057)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2109)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1462)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2472)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2057)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2109)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1462)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2472)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2057)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7520)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3374)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3306)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4400)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4378)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4482)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(22509):    at android.os.Looper.loop
D/dalvikvm(22509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1205K, 21% free 22090K/27719K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 51ms
D/dalvikvm( 2284): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2199K, 46% free 32415K/59399K, paused 119ms, total 119ms
E/Watchdog( 2284): !@Sync 388
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my code?
Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that ActivityStack activityStack is null, you should check out this video on how to debug android applications from eclipse  : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqHYbm9e05A

Comment: no, i checked that already. and thanks for the video, but i'm well aware of debugging...

Answer (score 0):

Have you put `PointsOfInterestActivity` in your AndroidManifest.xml file?  If you do not enter it, the app will crash... see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770295/android-crash-when-starting-activity).